# Truth Domain + Domain Wizard = 2nd level spells?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, spells, wizard, domains, spell-slots

Truth Domain, from Races of Eberron, has Detect Thoughts (WIZ 2) in the 1st level Domain Spell slot. With Domain Wizard, "a domain wizard automatically adds each new domain spell to her list of known spells as soon as she becomes able to cast it."

Does this classify as "being able to cast 2nd level arcane spells" as a WIZ 1? This seems to be a mistake in spell slot allocation in the Races of Eberron book, but I've been unable to find errata for it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Spells don't have an intrinsic level—only the level they appear at on a particular list.

For example, *dismissal* is at 5th level on the sor/wiz list, but 4th level on the cleric list. When a wizard casts it, he does so from a 5th-level spell slot, it would use 15+Int for DC (technically, DC = spell’s save DC - creature’s HD + your caster level), and so on. It is, quite simply and in all ways, a 5th-level spell for him. If he scribes a scroll of it, it costs  12.5 × 5 × level of caster. For a cleric, a 4th-level slot, 14+Wis for the DC, and so on. The scroll costs 12.5 × 4 × level of caster.

The same for your wizard with the truth domain—if casting *detect thoughts* from the truth domain list instead of the sor/wiz list, **it is a 1st-level spell, not a 2nd-level one**.

Comment: Perfect, thank you. To continue the process, would Versatile Spellcaster then be a viable method for casting 2nd level spells? You now "know" a viable WIZ 2 spell, and can cast it from either a 1st-level Domain slot or your newly-minted 2nd-level Versatile slot. I believe that works...

Comment: @Ragnarok340 There are many, many approaches that work. Versatile Spellcaster is one, since a wizard can scribe spells he can’t actually cast into his book, and then use Versatile Spellcaster to get a slot to prepare it in. Harder to qualify for, at least before 5th and the spontaneous divination ACF. Easier is Precocious Apprentice from _Complete Arcane_ page 185 (not the feats chapter), which just gives you a 2nd-level spell. There are many more options, and many can be combined. Not many tables will, or should, allow it, though.

Comment: What book puts the spell *identify* on the regular ol' cleric spell list as a 2nd-level spell? (All I'm aware of in core is the *identify* spell being the 2nd-level Magic domain spell.)

Comment: @HeyICanChan *Huh.* It has been a *long* time that I’ve been under the false impression that *identify* was a 2nd-level cleric spell. That makes it a pretty poor example then, I’ll find a better one.

Comment: @KRyan: May I interest you in [Dismissal](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/dismissal.htm)? Clr 4, Sor/Wiz 5.

Comment: @KRyan Agreed; lots of methods are available. This one just appeared to be one of the 'cheaper' options, especially for a campaign without feat retraining.  I suspected that it wouldn't be viable, since better munchkins than I would've found it ages ago, but this is perfect RAW for why that's the case. Thanks!